# JS if key exist, include to array

Tags: javascript, dictionary, transform

I'm stuck in mapping object to array.
I use map, but its add every object field in array and i got a lot of undefined.

```js
  const mapKey: { [key: string]: number } = {
   'hello': 3,
 };


 preferences = {
  hello: true,
  .....
  .....
 }

    const array = Object.entries(preferences).map(([key, value]) => {
      return mapKey[key] && { index: mapKey[key], visible: true };
    });
```

result is:

```js
[undefined, undefined....{ index: mapKey[key], visible: true }]
 
 but i need just [{ index: mapKey[key], visible: true }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method generates an array based on return value, it's not suited for requirement so use  [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
const array = Object.entries(preferences).reduce((arr, [key, value]) => {
   // push into the array only if defined
   columnIndexMap[key] && arr.push({ index: mapKey[key], visible: true });
   // return the array reference for next iteration
   return arr;
   // set initial value as empty array for the result
}, []);
```

One-liner solution:

```
const array = Object.entries(preferences).reduce((arr, [key, value]) => (columnIndexMap[key] && arr.push({ index: mapKey[key], visible: true }), arr), []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer with `reduce` of course works and is efficient. You can also use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + `map`. This has the disadvantage of looking at values twice, but has a readability advantage. Which is more important, of course, depends on your use-case. I would prefer the following unless there is so much data that the additional work is noticeable:

```js
const mapKey = { 'hello': 3, 'test':4, 'test2': 5};

let preferences = { hello: true, test:false, test2:true}

let filtered = Object.entries(preferences)
.filter(([k, visible]) => visible)
.map(([k, visible]) => ({ index: mapKey[k], visible }))

console.log(filtered)
```